# Criteria for gyroscope export restrictions

Tags: gps, gyro

Recently I tried to purchase a gyro for a GPS car tracking device I'm designing and Digi-Key refused to sell me since I'm outside US and that specific part (L3G4200D from STMicro) is export-restricted.
I imagined that it was due to its precision (maybe high enough to be used in a weapon guidance system) but every alternative I found was restricted too.

Anyone knows what are the specific criteria for making gyros export-controlled, and if that really affects all of them? If not, what would be the maximum allowed for the relevant parameters (precision & etc.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Bureau of Industry and Security](http://www.bis.doc.gov/policiesandregulations/04forpolcontrols/chap3_regstability.htm):

> Section 742.6 of the EAR requires a license for RS reasons to export
>   certain image-intensifier tubes, infrared focal plane arrays, certain
>   software and technology for inertial navigation systems,
>   **gyroscopes** and accelerometers, to all destinations except Canada. All license applications for **these items are reviewed on a
>   case-by-case basis to determine whether the export could contribute,
>   directly or indirectly, to a country’s military capabilities in a
>   manner that would destabilize or alter a region’s military balance
>   contrary to U.S. foreign policy interests.**

*(emphasis mine)*

Basically, it's a pretty good gyroscope. In theory, you could use this to make a weapon that is as good as or better than something that we have. So of course we can't let you have it.

As mentioned above, "these items are reviewed on a case-by-case basis". So there are no published criteria that I could find.

But a quick search on Mouser showed that there are a couple with a "EAR" tag in the description indicating export controlled. But there are plenty that don't have this tag. Such as the [A3G4250D](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/STMicroelectronics/A3G4250D/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMskzhF9uAtig9tCSUywjLhJNlDUOcEMFCE%3d) which seems to have very similar specs to the L3GD20.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Looking closely at the characteristic for these two, I noticed the main difference is that the restricted one has a range up to 2000 deg/s. That makes sense - a car wouldn't turn that fast unless in an accident, but a weapon...

Comment: @fceconel Just thinking about 2000 deg/s makes me dizzy. Getting really good components is usually easy if you're willing to sacrifice on one spec to get another. Getting really great components can be hard. Even within the US we can't get GPS chips that exceed 515 m/s speed _AND_ 18,000 m altitude. We can have one or the other, but not both.

Comment: @embedded.kyle Have you tried switching your GPS module into the so-called "flight mode". Most modules work under the assumption that you are operating them on board of low-speed/altitude vehicles. However, many modules allow disabling this assumption, turning them into less accurate but increasing the range of speed and altitude estimation hugely. Well known GPS modules manufacturers allow changing this configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, but ST Micro is a French/Italian company anyway! 
So the first move is to look for a non-US distributor...

Farnell [in the UK](http://uk.farnell.com/stmicroelectronics/l3g4200d/gyro-mems-3axis-16llga-16lga/dp/1872924) list it, but as "no longer manufactured" which seems like a bigger problem... they do have other gyros listed though.